# Add git repo to github client

Tags: git, github

I'm working with some friends on a project. Were using a git repo, which we push to and pull from a remote server (not github). I saw, that my friends, on Mac OS X, are using the github client for commiting, pushing, ... And I want to do the same on Windows 7.

My Git repo is stored in the Github folder, and I have the Github client installed. How can the Github client find the git repo? Do I have to create a new repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a new repository - there are basically two ways you can do it, cloning or adding.

You can push any changes you have made to your remote server, and then clone the remote repository using the GitHub client. The cloned repository will then be available in your local GitHub repositories, and you can start making changes and pushing/pulling as usual using the GitHub client.

[GitHub's own website](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-repositories-with-github-for-windows/) also says:

> "Adding repositories with GitHub for Windows: You can add any repository already on your hard drive by dragging the
> folder in from Explorer. If that folder is a Git repository, GitHub
> for Windows will import all of the history and connect it to your
> GitHub account.
> Another great way to add repositories is to clone them directly"

This is designed for using GitHub as the remote server, but it should work for a different remote repository.